# Ler algumas linhas de um arquivo

Tags: python

Tenho um arquivo com cerca 3 milhões de linhas.
Tenho que ler linha por linha e processar algumas modificações, e após essas modificações na linha armazenar o resultado em uma lista para depois gravar em outro arquivo.

O problema é performance. Tá muito lento.

Pensei em fazer da seguinte forma:
Vou dividir as linhas do arquivo por 10 (ex. 300000 linhas) e processar. Quando findar essas 300000 linhas, gravo o arquivo. Depois leio as outras 300000 e assim por diante, até findar as linhas do arquivo origem.

Minha pergunta é:
Considerando que eu tenho um arquivo com 3 milhões de linhas, eu gostaria de ler apenas um trecho de linhas do arquivo (de 300000 em 300000). Isso é possível em python?

Segue o método:

```
def processa_arquivos_rlt(arquivos_rlt, newFileName, sms):
try:
    for arquivo in arquivos_rlt:
        if Modulo.andamento_processo == 0:
            break

        Modulo.arquivo = 'Aguarde...'
        Modulo.arquivo = (arquivo[arquivo.rindex('/')+1:])
        contador = 1

        with open(arquivo, 'r') as linhas_rlt, open(newFileName, "at") as linhas_saida:
            for linha in linhas_rlt:
                if Modulo.andamento_processo == 0:
                    break

                item = [i.strip() for i in linha.split(";")]

                linha = Linha()

                linha.dddOrigem = item[2]
                linha.numeroOrigem = item[3]
                linha.valorBruto = item[15]
                if linha.valorBruto.find(",") > 0:
                    if len(''.join(linha.valorBruto[linha.valorBruto.rindex(",")+1:].split())) == 1:
                        linha.valorBruto = linha.valorBruto + '0'
                else:
                    if (len(linha.valorBruto)) <= 2:
                        linha.valorBruto = linha.valorBruto + '00'

                linha.valorBruto = re.sub(r'[^0-9]', '', linha.valorBruto)
                linha.dddDestino = item[7]
                linha.numeroDestino = item[8]
                linha.localidade = item[10]
                linha.codigoServico = item[17]
                linha.contrato = item[18]

                if 'claro' in arquivo.lower():
                    linha.operadora = '36'
                    #[Resolvi removendo esse trecho de código. Ao invés de executar
                    #uma consulta a cada iteração, agora eu executo a consulta apenas
                    #uma vez, coloco o resultado em uma lista e percorro essa lista. A
                    #consulta é feita apenas uma vez!]

                    """
                    cc = CelularesCorporativos.objects.filter(ddd=linha.dddOrigem, numero=linha.numeroOrigem)
                    if len(cc) > 0:
                        if 'vc1' in linha.localidade.lower() or 'sms' in linha.localidade.lower():
                                if linha.dddOrigem == linha.dddDestino:
                                    if int(linha.valorBruto) > 0:
                                        linha.valorBruto = '0'
                    """
                    #chamadas inválidas
                    if len(linha.numeroDestino) < 8 and linha.numeroDestino != '100' \
                        and int(linha.valorBruto) > 0:
                        if item[0] == '3' and linha.dddDestino == '10' \
                            and linha.numeroDestino == '0' and 'secretaria claro' in linha.localidade.lower():
                    ...
```

Comment: Você pode colocar o código que você já desenvolveu até então no corpo da pergunta?

Comment: Rapaz... Esse código está precisando de umas refatoradas, hein? =)

Comment: Resolvi da seguinte forma: dentro de cada iteração eu executava uma consulta ao banco de dados, isso consumia muita memória, uma vez que a lista era enorme. Então coloquei o resultado da consulta em uma lista e fazia a checagem à lista a cada iteração. Melhorou a performance e não teve estouro de memória!

Comment: Você poderia postar sua solução como resposta, e [aceitar sua própria resposta](http://meta.pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/1078/como-e-por-que-aceitar-uma-resposta)? Isso deixaria a pergunta mais organizada. Aqui não colocamos "resolvido" no título ou no corpo da pergunta (vou editar para remover ok?). Obrigado.

Comment: Use o projeto spark apache....

Answer (score 5):

Três milhões de linhas pode ser que demore mesmo - 
mas a melhor forma de tratar isso em Python, se
cada linha deve ser processada independente das demais, é
ler uma linha por vez, usando o próprio iterador embutido no objeto de arquivo aberto (file) do Python com um `for`. E também, gravar uma linha por vez.

Se a sua lentidão for por questão de memória (ao ler o arquivo todo
de uma vez, a máquina poderia estar entrando em SWAP, o que deixaria o
processo todo centenas de vezes mais lento), você resolve - se for por que a tarefa é demorada mesmo, pelo menos você poderá ver o arquivo de saída
ir aumentando de tamanho aos poucos, a medida que a tarefa é executada.

Olhando o seu código, você já está fazendo o processamento linha a linha, quando faz: `for linha in linhas_rlt:` - no entanto, um pouco acima, para saber o 
tamanho do arquivo você faz

```
totalLinhas = len(fi.readlines()) #abro e fecho o arquivo pra saber a qtd de linhas
```

Isso é probiitvo: não faça isso. Nao é simplesmente "abrir e fechar o arquivo" - você está lendo todo o arquivo pra memoria, simplesmente para contar quantas linhas tem. Tudo bem fazer isso para um arquivo de 30 - 40 linhas, mas já que é sua "base de dados",e você está com problema de performance, voce não deve fazer isso.

Na verdade não há como saber o comprimento de um arquivo de texto, em linhas, sem abri-lo e contar as linhas desta forma - só que.... é por isso que isso não é feito. Nesse caso especifico, passou da hora de você colocar suas informações num banco de dados relacional. Essa é a forma de tratar 3 milhões de registros textuais de forma rápida "e indolor".

Fiz algumas melhorias no seu código abaixo, mas nada que vá mais que dobrar a velocidade atual (o atual estará quase o dobro mais lento por conta da sua verificação de tamanho do arquivo, como escrevi acima).

A sugestão para o seu problema mesmo é colocar esses dados numa base de dados - pode ser o SQLite mesmo, que vem embutido no Python: 
Processamento de 3 milhões de registros já é algo pesado para fazer em arquivos texto puro (como você percebeu).

Essencialmente seu código de volta, com algumas modificaçõs e comentários pertinentes:

```
def processa_arquivos_rlt(arquivos_rlt, newFileName, sms):
    listaLinhas = [] #aqui  serao adicionadas as linhas modificadas
    # m,elhor nao ter isso, e guardar linha a linha no arquivo de saida!
    contador = 1


    totalLinhas = 0 #eu preciso saber a quantidade de linhas do arquivo, eu mostro pro usuário o andamento do processo.
    # melhornao! :-)

    try:
        for arquivo in arquivos_rlt: # eu leio 3 arquivos, então aqui vai um por vez
            # invertendo o teste do if e encerrando o "for" se o teste for verdadeiro:
            # dimijnuimos um nivel de identação de todo o código.
            # em vez de :
            #if Modulo.andamento_processo > 0: #classe estática pra não usar variável global (performance)
            # fazemos:
            if  Modulo.andamento_processo <= 0:
                continue
            # e removemos a identação de todo o código restante
            contador = 1

            # Aqui, a nao ser que "Modulo.arquivo" seja uma property que
            # vá criando um log, ou imprimindo tudo o que for colocado nela,
            # a proxima linha não faz nada, já que o conteudo da variável
            # será sobre-escrito na linha seguinte.
            Modulo.arquivo = 'Aguarde...'
            Modulo.arquivo = (arquivo[arquivo.rindex('/')+1:])
            # voce porde até dobrar o tempo da tarefa com as linhas abaixo: desligadas
            #fi = open(arquivo, 'r')
            #totalLinhas = len(fi.readlines()) #abro e fecho o arquivo pra saber a qtd de linhas
            fi.close()

            # Abrir o arquivo de gravacao junto, e gravar linha a linha, em vez de mater uma lista:
            # abrir o aruivo com o modo "at" mantem o conteudo do arquivo já existente e abre no final
            # para escrita de novos dados:


            with open(arquivo, 'r') as linhas_rlt, open(newFilename, "at") as linhas_saida:
                for linha in linhas_rlt:
                    #if Modulo.andamento_processo > 0: #se for = a zero eu cancelo o processo.
                    # entao, vamos fazer isso: cancelar o processo se a variavel for zero,
                    # e diminuir um nivel de identação.
                    if Modulo.andamento_processo == 0: # inverte o if acima
                        break # e sai do processo se o valor for zero
                    # tiramos todo o códgigo abaixo de dentro do if
                    # meno sum nivel de identacao = codigo mais agraael de ler:

                    # A linha abaixo funciona - mas considere trocar a leitura do arquivo para usar
                    # o módulo "csv" do Python em vez de fazer o split manualmente.
                    # O principal motivo é que se você tiver campos com texto
                    # que possam estar entre aspas, ou possam conter o caractere ";"
                    # o módulo csv trata pra você:

                    item = [i.strip() for i in linha.split(";")]

                    linha = Linha()


                    # Aqui entrama s linahs onde voce processa o conteudo, e etc...
                    # a principio nada que deva deixar muito lento.

                    #para gravar:
                    # em vez de adicionar o objeto "linha" em uma lista, grava-lo imediatamente:

                    #listaLinhas.append(linha)

                    linhas_saida.writeline(<seu código para serializar o objeto 'Linha'> + "\n")
```

Comment: Fiz seguindo seu conselho mas deu erro de MemoryError Unhandled exception in thread started by...
Tipo, estourou a memória quando tinha lido e gravado algo em torno de 190 mil linhas...

É um absurdo! Fiz isso em java e funcionou perfeitamente. Resolvi migrar pra python e não consigo. Não justifica eu ter que criar uma tabela para colocar os dados do arquivo, tratá-los e depois gerar outro arquivo! Deve ter um meio!

Acima eu coloquei o método completo. Deve ter algum furo pra dar estouro de memória. Se puder ajudar...

Answer (score 0):

Armazene em um arquivo o número da linha que está sendo lida, ao iniciar o processo o script lê o número da linha e começa por ela ou pela primeira, caso a linha não seja informada. Para saber o número da linha, use uma variável que se incremente a cada laço do loop.

Answer (score -1):

No seu lugar, eu colocaria o processo inteiro em *thread* usando a biblioteca nativa `multiprocessing`:

https://docs.python.org/2/library/multiprocessing.html

Por exemplo:

```
from multiprocessing import Process
import os

def processa_arquivos_rlt(arquivos_rlt, newFileName, sms):
    listaLinhas = [] #aqui vai ser adicionado as linhas modificadas
    contador = 1
    totalLinhas = 0 #eu preciso saber a quantidade de linhas do arquivo, eu mostro pro usuário o andamento do processo.

try:
    for arquivo in arquivos_rlt: # eu leio 3 arquivos, então aqui vai um por vez
        p = Process(target=worker_function, args=(arquivo,))
        p.start()
        p.join()

def worker_function(arquivo):
    if Modulo.andamento_processo > 0: #classe estática pra não usar variável global (performance)
            contador = 1
            Modulo.arquivo = 'Aguarde...'
            Modulo.arquivo = (arquivo[arquivo.rindex('/')+1:])
            fi = open(arquivo, 'r')
            totalLinhas = len(fi.readlines()) #abro e fecho o arquivo pra saber a qtd de linhas
            fi.close()

            with open(arquivo, 'r') as linhas_rlt:
                for linha in linhas_rlt:
                    if Modulo.andamento_processo > 0: #se for = a zero eu cancelo o processo.
                        item = [i.strip() for i in linha.split(";")]

                        linha = Linha()

                        linha.dddOrigem = item[2]
                        linha.numeroOrigem = item[3]
                        linha.valorBruto = item[15]
                        if linha.valorBruto.find(",") > 0:
                            if len(''.join(linha.valorBruto[linha.valorBruto.rindex(",")+1:].split())) == 1:
                                linha.valorBruto = linha.valorBruto + '0'
                        else:
                            if (len(linha.valorBruto)) <= 2:
                                linha.valorBruto = linha.valorBruto + '00'

                        linha.valorBruto = re.sub(r'[^0-9]', '', linha.valorBruto)
                        linha.dddDestino = item[7]
                        linha.numeroDestino = item[8]
                        linha.localidade = item[10]
                        linha.codigoServico = item[17]
                        linha.contrato = item[18]
```

PS: Eu não testei este código. É só uma sugestão inicial do que é possível fazer.

Comment: Colocar em várias threads não facilita o problema de memória, nem, sem outros recursos, vai te dar algum ganho muito bom com Python (pode ser que ele contorne o I/O bloqueante para ler linhas do arquivo, então pode sim ter ganho). Outra ocisa - thread != multiprocessing: sao coisas completamente ditintas) e por fim, usando ou threads ou multi-processing, fica dificil garantir que a ordem das linhas no arquivo de saida vai respeitar a ordem do arquivo inicial. Nao sabemos se 'e um requisito do O.P (original poster: "a pessoa que fez a pergunta") - mas na dúvida, melhor preservar.